# Fixed 100% height sidebar that after scroll stick to footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to get my fixed 100% height sidebar when atteint the top of the footer go from fixed position to absolute position withe specific given height and stick to footer.

> HTML Structure

```
<header ng-include="'app/views/partials/application-specific/top-navbar.html'"></header>
<section ng-include="'app/views/partials/user/top-back-user.html'"></section>
<div class="content">
  <aside class="aside sidebar" id="stick" ng-include="'app/views/partials/user/sidebar-user.html'" style="max-height: 100% !important;"></aside>

 <div class="content-wrapper" id="content-wrapper" ui-view>
 </div>
</div>
<footer class="footer" id="footer" ng-include="'app/views/partials/user/footer.html'"style="padding-bottom: 0px; height:300px;" ></footer>
```

> 1- the first javascript code serve to fix the sidebar to top after 150px scroll.

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
if (windowWidth > 991) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
            $('#menu1-fixed').addClass('fixed1');
            $('.fado').slideUp();
            $('.fado').slideUp(600);
        } else {
            $('#menu1-fixed').removeClass('fixed1');
            $('.fado').slideDown();
            $('.fado').slideDown(600);
        }
    })
};
```

**css**

```
.fixed1 {
   position:fixed !important; top: 0em !important; margin-top: 3.4em !important;
}
```

> 2- The second code is after scroll 900px from top replace fixed position with absolute and a specific height. In that case i wannt to change 900px to detect the top of the footer and after change class to absolute.

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
if (windowWidth > 991) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 900) {
            $('#menu1-fixed').addClass('main-sidebar2');
        } else {
            $('#menu1-fixed').removeClass('main-sidebar2');
        }
    })
};
```

**css**

```
.main-sidebar2 {
  position: absolute !important;
  height:600px !important;
  min-height: 580px !important;
  top:1000px !important;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks in advance for your help !!!

Comment: there is a live example of semantic-ui you can check  https://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html

Answer (score 1):

please try with below example it will work fine.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var e = $("#stick");
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    var firstOffset = e.offset().top;
    var lastA = e.offset().top;
    var isFixed = false;
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        if (isFixed) {
            return;
        }
        var a = e.offset().top;
        var b = e.height();
        var c = $(window).height();
        var d = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (b <= c - a) {
            e.css({position: "fixed"});
            isFixed = true;
            return;
        }           
        if (d > lastScrollTop){ // scroll down
            if (e.css("position") != "fixed" && c + d >= a + b) {
                e.css({position: "fixed", bottom: 0, top: "auto"});
            }
            if (a - d >= firstOffset) {
                e.css({position: "absolute", bottom: "auto", top: lastA});
            }
        } else { // scroll up
            if (a - d >= firstOffset) {
                if (e.css("position") != "fixed") {
                    e.css({position: "fixed", bottom: "auto", top: firstOffset});
                }
            } else {
                if (e.css("position") != "absolute") {
                    e.css({position: "absolute", bottom: "auto", top: lastA});
                }               
            }
        }
        lastScrollTop = d;
        lastA = a;
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try and i will let you know !! thanks !!

Comment: i tried but it dosen't seems to work. you will find elow the html structure

Comment: Did you changed the id?

Comment: Yes of corse i changed the id

Comment: I also modified my post so you can view the HTML structure of the page!!